# ¿Cómo puedo remover un placeholder de un jtextfile?

Tags: java

```
 TextPrompt placeholder = new TextPrompt("Apellido Paterno", jtexfile);
 placeholder.changeAlpha(0.75f);

 TextPrompt placeholder2 = new TextPrompt("Apellido Materno", jtexfile);
 placeholder2.changeAlpha(0.75f);
```

Al agregar dos `placerholder` a un solo elemento, los concatena, como puedo hacer que se reinicie.

Comment: La pregunta es cuando se reinicia, o cuándo querés que se remueva del JTextField?, porque imagino es un JTextField nó o estoy equivocado?, no conozco el JTextFile, ni sabía que hay una clase que se llama TextPrompt, desde lo que pude entender te voy a dejar una respuesta para que juegues con eso y le busques una solución vos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acá te dejo una respuesta que **no sé si exactamente hace lo que pedís**, sin embargo creo que no lo tengo claro, porque **no especificás cuando** tiene que ocurrir el **cambio de placeholder**, también hay que tener en cuenta que si estás trabajando con librerías swing las mismas no tienen un método específico para adherir un placeholder (Que yo sepa, realmente no conozco TextPrompt), sólo se setea el texto que querés que diga, si uno quiere hacer un **placeholder** en **swing** debe **hacerlo personalizado**. En **javaFx sí hay** pero es otro tema.

Te dejo código con algunos **eventos** que **suceden** al tocar **click** sobre los **JTextField** o tocar **Enter**.

**Copiá** el código en una clase que se llame "**Panel**" y dale "**Run as java application**".

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.soa.utilities.TextPrompt;

public class Panel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4, label5;
    private JTextField field1, field2, field3, field4, fieldWithPromtText;
    private TextPrompt placeholder;

    public Panel() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        field1 = new JTextField("Apellido Paterno", 25);
        field2 = new JTextField("Apellido Materno", 25);
        field3 = new JTextField("Tocá Enter acá", 25);
        field4 = new JTextField("Escribí algo acá", 25);
        fieldWithPromtText = new JTextField(10);

        placeholder = new TextPrompt("Apellido Paterno", fieldWithPromtText);
        placeholder.changeAlpha(0.75f);
        placeholder.changeStyle(Font.ITALIC);

        /* Labels */
        label1 = new JLabel("Cambio de texto al salir o entrar del input");
        label2 = new JLabel("Cambio de texto al salir o entrar del input");
        label3 = new JLabel("Cambio de texto al tocar enter o un button");
        label4 = new JLabel("Evento con acciones al enter o un button");
        label5 = new JLabel("Evento con clase descargada de internet");
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(field1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(field2);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(field3);
        panel.add(label4);
        panel.add(field4);
        panel.add(label5);
        panel.add(fieldWithPromtText);
        frame.add(panel);

        /* Escucha el cambio de inputs */
        field1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                field1.setText("Apellido Paterno");

            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                field1.setEnabled(true);
                field1.setText("");

            }
        });
        ;

        /* Escucha el cambio de inputs */
        field2.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                field2.setText("Apellido Materno");

            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                field2.setText("");

            }
        });

        /* Escucha si hay algún button o la tecla enter para cambiar */
        field3.addActionListener(event -> field3.setText("Tocaste enter!!!"));

        field4.addActionListener(event -> {
            System.out.println("Escribiste: " + field4.getText());
            field4.setText("Ahora el otro placeholder, pero mirá la consola...");
        });

        /*
         * Acá utilicé ésa clase, la cual la encontré por internet, cuando ingresás un
         * dato y tocas enter realiza una acción y luego cambia el placeholder
         */
        fieldWithPromtText.addActionListener(event -> {
            fieldWithPromtText.setText("");
            System.out.println("El placeholder debería haber cambiado, checkear");
            fieldWithPromtText.remove(placeholder);
            placeholder = new TextPrompt("Apellido Materno", fieldWithPromtText);
            placeholder.changeAlpha(0.75f);
            placeholder.changeStyle(Font.ITALIC);
        });

        frame.setTitle("JTextField");

        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();
    }

}
```

**Edito:**

Buscando un poco por internet encontré que [TextPrompt](http://www.camick.com/java/source/TextPrompt.java) es una **clase** no nativa libre, creada para swing por [Rob Camick](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/). Para utilizarla se copia el contenido a una Clase que se llame **TextPrompt** dentro del mismo proyecto y listo, la utilicé e hice un ejemplo tocando "**Enter**" sobre el input, el resultado es que **cambia** el **placeholder** pero antes realiza una acción, espero que el código que arriba te dejé te sirva de algo.

El **último input** es el que más **se asemeja** a lo que pedís, si es que no entendí mal.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me falto dar mas explicacion por mi problema, pero me ayudo parte de tu codigo para entenderlo.